# get private repo branch via github api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I want to get all branch name in my private repo via github api .
It's success when I use cli, but i get error code 404 when i use axios in react app .
I'm sure that my url and token is correct in both cli and react app .
By the way , my react app can successfully get public repo branch name but not include private.

my Js code

```
const owner = 'Solo-steven';
const token = MYTOKEN;
const repo = 'Sideex-private-test'
async function getPrivateBranchName(){

    await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url : `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/branches`,
        header:{
            Authorization: `token ${token}`
        }
    }).then(response=>{
        console.log(response, `Success get all branch name of repo(${repo}).`)
    }).catch(response=>{
        console.log(response, `error when get branch name of repo(${repo})`);
    })
}
```

my Cli

```
 curl -H "Authorization: token MYTOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/Solo-steven/Sideex-private-test/branches
```

Comment: You have a typo `headers` instead of `header`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios it is headers not header